# What's the difference between .kt and .kts files in Kotlin. When should we use .kts file over .kt file?

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

What is the purpose of using .kts files in Kotlin? Are these files included in the app bundle when releasing the app?

[image]

Comment: You can check this in your apk

Answer (score 65, accepted):

`.kt` — normal source files, `.kts` — script files

You don't need the `main` function in a `.kts` file, It will be executed line by line just like a bash/python script.

The `.kts` files don't need separate compilation. You run them using the following command:

```
kotlinc -script <filename>.kts
```

Answer (score 13):

**.Kt and .Kts**

- They are all kotlin files that contain kotlin source code.
- .kt file are assumed to be compiled by the kotlin compiler.
- .Kts files are assumed to be executed by kotlin scriting support.

**As Explained in** *kolinConf18*